# VBA Center Align ListBox Text

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I have trouble in aligning my ListBox text to Center
I search but can't find answer..

I try to align the source into center but the ListBox doesn't fallow

Is their a way to align this to center?

Here is my figure

[image]

I forgot to share that my ListBox is inside UserForm and to such Text-Aling = Center found in the properties

[image]

Comment: I see I need to drag more in the buttom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click the ListBox (Default `ListBox1`). In the Properties, click `TextAlign`. Change this to:

`2 - fmtTextAlignCenter`

You can also change to the `Categorized` tab and under `Behavior`, you will also see `TextAlign`.

[image]

Comment: sorry I need to drag more in the buttom

Answer (score 2):

In the UserForm designer in the VBE, select your userform and click on the listbox.

In the Properties window, find the TextAlign property. Set it to:

2 - fmTextAlignCenter